# How to convert est datetime String into GMT datetime in java

Tags: java, datetime, gmt

I tried below to get GMT Time

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyyHHmmss");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = f.parse("13072016132825");
System.out.println("GMT Time"+f.format(date.getTime()));
```

Comment: You need capital MM for months, not mm.

Comment: @ David I tried with capital MM Still I am getting same string in input.

Comment: Sure.  But you haven't actually said what your problem is, or asked a question.  That's why I didn't provide an answer (and it baffles me that two people provided answers without knowing what the question is).  So, what's actually going wrong for you?  How can I help?

Comment: I have string which contains EST datetime and I wants to convert it to GMT datetime.

Comment: Yes, and what is going wrong for you, when you try the code above?

Comment: Probably, you need to set the time zone to EST, then call `f.parse`.  After that, set the time zone to GMT and call `f.format`.  As it is, you're doing your `parse` step with a `SimpleDateFormat` whose time zone is GMT.

Comment: @BasilBourque this is almost certainly NOT a duplicate of that other question.

Comment: @DavidWallace The problem and the solution is the same, using `mm` versus `MM` in the formatting pattern. And many many others as well. Do you suggest Stack Overflow have a Question for every possible permutation of parsing pattern all sharing the same `MM` problem?

Comment: @BasilBourque the OP hasn't even clarified what the problem is yet; although they've said quite clearly it's not the `mm` vs `MM` thing.  So NOT a duplicate.  I suspect it's the fact that they're doing the `parse` with the wrong timezone, but I don't know.

Comment: When the author edits their Question to first eliminate the obvious syntax problem, and secondly clarify the underlying nature of the unspecified problem, we can reopen the Question. But it seems silly to entertain a Question asking about code that can't possibly be working.

Comment: Fair enough, although "unclear what you're asking" would have been a better close reason than "duplicate of ..." when it's clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @david now I got it.